# Trying to add Related Record List to community

Tags: community, related-list

When I add a related record list component to a community page, I receive the message "Unfortunately, the related list you're trying to view isn't in the layout.  Please get in touch with your administrator."  The related list is in the page layout.  I can see the related list fine when I am looking at it via Salesforce Lightning.  This is happening for any related list I try to include on the community page.  I have never tried to do this before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was not using the correct related list name.  I found the correct related list name by going to displaying the related list in Lightning & copying what appeared in the URL for the related list name.  For me, the format looked something like Project_Organization__r